# LoadError: MethodError: no method matching mod(::VariableRef, ::Float64)

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm new to Julia and JuMP, a library I'm going to use.

Trying to define the following constraint, after having defined the variables, I receive an error:

```
for r = 1:11
    for d = 1:7
        for s = 1:12
            @constraint(model, mod(ris_day_ora[r,d,s],0.5)==0)
        end
    end
end
```

Here the error:

ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching mod(::VariableRef, ::Float64)

Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `mod` in a JuMP constraint.

You need to reformulate the model and there are many ways to do that.
In your case the easiest thing would be to declare `ris_day_ora` as `Int` and then divide it everywhere by `2`.

```
@variable(model, ris_day_ora[1:11, 1:7, 1:12] >=0, Int)
```

And now everywhere in the code use `ris_day_ora[r,d,s]/2.0` instead of `ris_day_ora[r,d,s]`.

#### Edit:

if your variable `ris_day_ora` takes three values `0`, `0.5`, `1` you just model it as:

```
@variable(model, 0 <= ris_day_ora[1:11, 1:7, 1:12] <= 2, Int)
```

And in each place in model use it as `0.5 * ris_day_ora[r,d,s]`

#### Edit 2

Perhaps you are looking for a more general solution. Consider `x` that can only be either `0.1`, `0.3`, `0.7` this could be written as:

```
@variable(model, x)
@variable(model, helper[1:3], Bin)
@contraint(model, x == 0.1*helper[1] + 0.3*helper[2] + 0.7*helper[3])
@contraint(model, sum(helper) == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw! The variable ris_day_ora, in my case, should be one of these values: 0, 0.5, 1. How can I model the constraint?